# CentOS 7 vulnerabilities

Tags: security, centos-7

I installed CentOS 7 and I am requested to update some packages due to some vulnerabilities. I can see there are updates for RedHat, and it looks like I can also use the RedHat Network, but I have no idea how.

`yum update` tells me there are no updates, and Googling for "CentOS 7 CVE-*" gives no real results. It is about fairly recent exploits.

How can I update my CentOS7 with the latest security fixes?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Considering CentOS 7 is the current version its possible these vulnerabilities have not been patched yet.  I would just wait until the CentOS developers test and released the patches.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated my question with a question :). I want to update my system with the latest security fixes, but it seems they are only available through the RHN, which I cannot subscribe to (or can I?)

Comment: Even though you can you shouldn't because RedHat is concern with compatibility with their releases not CentOS

Comment: @Ramhound so all I can do is wait until CentOS releases the fixes through `yum update` and install them?

Comment: @BartFriederichs, yes, unless you are specifically and drastically affected by a particular vulnerability, it is always best practice to wait until your distro has imported upstream changes. Tracking CVEs is a full time job, so unless it is your job, its best to let someone else do it.